# Settings for moving recurring payments to Stripe

Tags: extension, payment-processor, paypal, recurring-contributions, stripe

I am in the process of moving from Paypal to stripe. Stripe has has an enquiry as follows:

"Please let me know if the data should be imported as cards[0] or card sources[1]. If you're not sure, I recommend checking in with your developer team and/or any third-party integrations you plan on using, as they may only support one of these object types.

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/saving-cards
[1] https://stripe.com/docs/sources/cards"

Can anyone suggest which link of the above is used for stripe extension please? thanks

Comment: are you based in Europe? if it's the case, I'd recommend you to postpone the project after 15th of sept, lots of changes are coming (SCA) that will have an impact on stripe extension, and might on the source vs card question